# Let A, B and C be sets. Prove that $A \cap (B-C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Someone please edit so the & symbol is the intersect (reverse of U).

This is a recent question on proofs homework. From what I understand, intersect and minus symbols used in equations for sets can be manipulated and distributive properties and other inferences can be made. Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2):

In general, to prove two sets are equal, you show they are subsets of each other.

Let's do one direction: we'll show $A \cap (B - C) \subset (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$. Let $x \in  A \cap (B - C)$. So $x \in A $ and $x \in (B - C)$ which means $x \in B, x \notin C$. Since $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, $x \in (A \cap B)$. And since $x \notin C, x \notin (A \cap C)$. Therefore $x \in (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$. Since x was arbitrary, this proves the inclusion.

The other direction is similar.

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\notag \\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \notag \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\notag \end{align}}
$I would treat this as a simplification problem using the laws of logic: start at the most complex side, and calculates which elements $\;x\;$ are in that set:

$$\calc
x \in (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\setminus\;$}
x \in A \cap B \;\land\; \lnot(x \in A \cap C)
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\cap\;$, twice}
x \in A \land x \in B \;\land\; \lnot(x \in A \land x \in C)
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: use $\;x \in A\;$ on other side of $\;\land\;$}
x \in A \land x \in B \;\land\; \lnot(\text{true} \land x \in C)
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: simplify}
x \in A \land x \in B \land x \not\in C
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\setminus\;$}
x \in A \land x \in B \setminus C
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\cap\;$}
x \in A \cap (B \setminus C)
\endcalc$$